# Detecting brackets in input string

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making an application that is able to read a string and convert it to musical notation.

Let's say I have an input here :

> [ 0 [ [ 5 6 ] ] ]

originally no spaces between character. Just for readability sake here.

and this is the output I want to achieve :

[image]

So, that's mean I got to detect (the simple algorithm / program flow) is :

1. If there is a bracket I need to find the deepest set of brackets (in this case, 5 6) AND DETECTING HOW MANY BRACKETS WRAPPING THEM (in this case 2)
2. Drawing X (X=number of brackets) lines on 5 and 6 (in this case, 2)
3. After that I need to find the character on the outside of the bracket (in this case, 0), and how many brackets wrapping them (in this case 1)
4. Drawing 1 line on the same level of the topmost of the last drawn line and connect them.

So,
**Summary :**

How to do step 1 and 3 (detecting brackets on a string), since I already know how to draw lines on a canvas.

Btw, if you have another more efficient rather than my algorithm (1-4), please elaborate.

Thanks. Please feel free to clarify anything.

**UPDATE** : Deleting the [ 0 [ 5 6 ] ] example, since it's incorrect.

**UPDATE 2** :

More examples

[ 1 2 3 ]

[image]

[ [ [ 2 3 ] ] 1 ]

[image]

[ [ 3 4 ] ]

[image]

[ 1 2 ]

[image]

If you need more samples, feel free to ask.

Comment: What is the output for `[ 0 [ 5 6 ] ]`? One line across all three?

Comment: if in the numerical sheet, it's just the same (as my example), but it's not convertible if I wanna use the string on block note (the kind of musical sheet using bar lines), since it's fundamentally different (I guess, since I'm not quite sure too about it, if anyone have an experience on music better than me, let me know)

What i planned on one line accross all three is `[ 0 5 6 ]`

Comment: Your algorithm will clearly not produce the same output for both inputs - in the second example `5 6` is only directly nested in one level of brackets and so you can not get two bars according to your description.

Comment: oh right, I forgot about "the last line drawn has the same level of the topmost level of the last drawn line". So, yes, I think I'll have some 'autocorrect' if there's [ 0 [ 5 6 ] ] into [ 0 5 6 ]. Thanks for your question, it's enlighten me in a different thing.

Comment: Can you provide more example input output pairs?

Comment: You're asking us _"Develop a parser and renderer for me"_, which is too broad. Please show your code and explain what parts specifically you're having trouble with.

Comment: @DanielBrückner got a few more samples

Comment: @CodeCaster umm I think I wasn't asking a parser? I meant, I just need how you guys process and detecting brackets, since that's pretty basic for my code, surely I haven't code anything good to show.

Comment: Are your absolutely sure that `[ 0 [ [ 5 6 ] ] ]` should not have 3 bars over `5 6`? This would make way more sense given your other examples.

Comment: Oh, my second "additional example" is wrongly written. it should be `[ [ [ 2 3 ] ] 1 ]` forgive me.

Comment: Finally, I found the answer posted here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606376/how-to-process-an-array-correctly/23613919#23613919 If someone got a better answer, feel free to post!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to process an array correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606376/how-to-process-an-array-correctly)

Comment: @DourHighArch that's also a thread of mine, similar, but has a different approach. This problem is deemed to wide, I then created a narrower one there.

Answer (score 0):

This does the right thing for both of your examples but I have no clue if it is correct in the general case. It also does not perform any checks to see whether the input is well formed.

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();

var digits = new List<Char>();

var numberBars = new List<Int32>();

var currentNumberBars = 0;

var newScope = true;

foreach (var symbol in input)
{
    if (symbol == '[')
    {
        currentNumberBars = newScope ? 1 : currentNumberBars + 1;

        newScope = false;
    }
    else if ((symbol >= '0') && (symbol <= '9'))
    {
        digits.Add(symbol);
        numberBars.Add(currentNumberBars);

        newScope = true;
    }
}

var maximumNumberBars = numberBars.Max();

Console.WriteLine();

for (var i = 0; i < digits.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(digits[i] + new String('|', numberBars[i]).PadLeft(maximumNumberBars));
}
```

**Sample outputs**

```
[ 0 [ [ 5 6 ] ] ]

0 |
5||
6||

[ 0 5 6 ]

0|
5|
6|

[ 1 [[ 2 3 ]] 4 [[[ 5 [[ 6 ]] 7 ]]]]

1  |
2 ||
3 ||
4 ||
5|||
6 ||
7 ||
```

I just recognized that it is probably wrong because it does not correctly close the scopes but it is hard to tell from your description of the problem and I have no idea what the background is. For what is this notation used in music?

Comment: it's for marking note's length. look http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbered_musical_notation and find for "Note Length". The eighth, 16th and such part.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different algorithm that makes the current nesting level the number of bars. It works correctly for all your examples except `[ 0 [ [ 5 6 ] ] ]` which receives 3 bars over `5 6` but it seems way more intuitive to me than my first answer.

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();

var digits = new List<Char>();

var numberBars = new List<Int32>();

var currentNumberBars = 0;

foreach (var symbol in input)
{
    if (symbol == '[')
    {
        currentNumberBars++;
    }
    else if (symbol == ']')
    {
        if (currentNumberBars == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        currentNumberBars--;
    }
    else if ((symbol >= '0') && (symbol <= '9'))
    {
        digits.Add(symbol);
        numberBars.Add(currentNumberBars);
    }
}

if (currentNumberBars != 0)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}

var maximumNumberBars = numberBars.Max();

Console.WriteLine();

for (var i = 0; i < digits.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(digits[i] + new String('|', numberBars[i]).PadLeft(maximumNumberBars));
}
```