# How to process an array correctly

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, string

Here's the part 1 of my question, if you wanna check the background of this question :

[Detecting brackets in input string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581002/detecting-brackets-in-input-string/23581913?noredirect=1#23581913)

Forgive me if the title doesn't match, since I also confused how to name it appropriately to picture my problem. If anyone knows a more appropriate title, feel free to edit.

So, given below code (my own code) :

```
    private const int PARTICLE_EACH_CHAR = 4;

    /*ProcessBarLines : string s only contains numbers, b, [,  and ]*/
    private int ProcessBarLines(Canvas canvas, string s, int lastLineAboveNotation)
    {
        List<int> bracket = new List<int>();
        List<int> other = new List<int>();
        int currentCloseNumber = 0;
        int currentOpenNumber = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (s[i] == '[')
            {
                bracket.Add(i);
                currentOpenNumber++;
                if (i - 1 > 0 && s[i - 1] != '[')
                {
                    currentOpenNumber = 1;
                }
            }
            else if (s[i] == ']')
            {
                bracket.Add(i);
                currentCloseNumber++;

                if (i + 1 >= s.Length || s[i + 1] != ']' || currentOpenNumber == currentCloseNumber)
                {
                    int min = bracket.Count - (currentCloseNumber * 2);
                    int max = bracket[bracket.Count - 1];

                    List<int> proc = new List<int>();

                    int firstIndex = -1;
                    int lastIndex = -1;

                    for (int ii = 0; ii < other.Count; ii++)
                    {
                        if (other[ii] > min && other[ii] < max)
                        {
                            proc.Add(other[ii]);

                            if (firstIndex == -1)
                            {
                                firstIndex = ii;
                                lastIndex = ii;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lastIndex = ii;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    double leftPixel = firstIndex * widthEachChar;
                    double rightPixel = (lastIndex * widthEachChar) + widthEachChar;

                    DrawLine(canvas, currentCloseNumber, leftPixel,
                        rightPixel, lastLineAboveNotation * heightEachChar / PARTICLE_EACH_CHAR);

                    lastLineAboveNotation += currentCloseNumber - 1;

                    currentOpenNumber -= currentCloseNumber;
                    currentCloseNumber = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                other.Add(i);
            }
        }

        return lastLineAboveNotation + 1;
    }
```

Here's the test cases :

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

[image: Picture 3]

Picture 1 & 2 is the correct answer, and picture 3 is the wrong answer. Picture 3 should have a line, just like inverted from number 2, but, apparently, (if you look closely) the line is drawn on the right, but it should be on the left to be correct (above `0`).

I figured, the problem is, I'm quite sure on the "min". Since it doesn't give the correct starting value.

Any idea on this? Feel free to clarify anything. It's used for writing numeric musical scores.

Btw, `DrawLine()` just meant to draw the line above the numbers, it's not the problem.

Comment: Which picture is meant to be which? There are three pictures, but no indication of which is which...

Comment: This problem is recursive in nature so it's probably more natural to use a recursively formulated algorithm to solve it. What's the real intended output - these lines, or are they just for debugging?

Comment: @JonSkeet, if you follow the question author's description of the problem then you can work out that their pictures are just numbered vertically from top to bottom, 1, 2 & 3. From what I understand, their problem is that the (thinner) black line at the top (of the bottom picture) should go across all three numbers.

Comment: @Sheridan: They weren't top to bottom before - look at the first revision.

Comment: it's now in the correct order. sorry for the scrambled picture

Comment: @500-InternalServerError those lines are the real intended output.

Answer (score 0):

Finally! I found it!

```
    private int ProcessBarLines(Canvas canvas, string s, int lastLineAboveNotation)
    {
        List<int> bracket = new List<int>();
        List<int> other = new List<int>();
        int currentCloseNumber = 0;
        int currentOpenNumber = 0;
        int space = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (s[i] == '[')
            {
                bracket.Add(i);
                currentOpenNumber++;
                if (i - 1 > 0 && s[i - 1] != '[')
                {
                    currentOpenNumber = 1;
                }
            }
            else if (s[i] == ']')
            {
                bracket.Add(i);
                currentCloseNumber++;

                if (i + 1 >= s.Length || s[i + 1] != ']' || currentOpenNumber == currentCloseNumber)
                {

                    int min = bracket[Math.Max(bracket.Count - ((currentCloseNumber * 2) + space), 0)];
                    int max = bracket[bracket.Count - 1];

                    space = max - min - 1;

                    List<int> proc = new List<int>();

                    int firstIndex = -1;
                    int lastIndex = -1;

                    for (int ii = 0; ii < other.Count; ii++)
                    {
                        if (other[ii] > min && other[ii] < max)
                        {
                            proc.Add(other[ii]);
                            other[ii] = -1;
                            if (firstIndex == -1)
                            {
                                firstIndex = ii;
                                lastIndex = ii;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lastIndex = ii;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    double leftPixel = firstIndex * widthEachChar;
                    double rightPixel = (lastIndex * widthEachChar) + widthEachChar;

                    DrawLine(canvas, currentCloseNumber, leftPixel,
                        rightPixel, lastLineAboveNotation * heightEachChar / PARTICLE_EACH_CHAR);

                    lastLineAboveNotation += 1;

                    currentOpenNumber -= currentCloseNumber;
                    currentCloseNumber = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                other.Add(i);
            }
        }

        return lastLineAboveNotation + 1;
    }
```

If someone got a more efficient code, please let us know!